# UITextField Clear Button Calls didEndEditing Twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a UITextField with a Clear button. Whenever the user resigns first responder on the textfield, it submits the change to a webservice.

When the user taps the clear button, seemingly, the textfield loses its first responder status, causing the didEndEditing delegate method to be called. So the webservice call is made, with the old, populated value. Then, the textfield is cleared, calling didEndEditing again, calling the webservice again.

Why does this happen this way? I would expect the clear button to empty the text and then call didEndEditing on the delegate so you only get one message.

Comment: By "Clear button" do you mean the embedded clear button in the textfield or a custom button of yours ? The default clear button should just clear the text in the field, not call didEndEditing. Some code of the part where you handle the keyboard and the text field would help.

Comment: Add a tag for the language you are talking about, and the ui-framework/device. Then experts will notice your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the built in clear button on the UITextField, when the user taps it that causes the text field to loose focus as the button itself receives the touch - this triggers the first `-didEndEditing`. Then the release of the clear button causes it to clear the text field, which calls `-didEndEditing` to fire yet again when the text is actually cleared. Yeah, it is definitely less than ideal.